# Using flexbox how do I prevent a specific element from inheriting flex layout?

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I have a module `.m-standout` that uses `display:flex` and consists of a heading, sub text and an image. Basically I would like to use flex to position the heading and sub text but then let the image take up 100% width below, at the moment however the image takes up a 3rd column. Can anyone advise how I can prevent the image from using flex, I was trying something like `flex:0` and `flex:none` with no joy.

**CSS**

```
.m-standout {
    display: flex;

    .standout-heading {
        font-size: 34px;
        width: 31.28834%;
        align-self: center;

    }

     .standout-desc {
        width: 52.76074%;
        align-self: center;
    }

    .standout-image {

    }
}
```

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/styler/pen/gLaCw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.m-standout`.

**SCSS:**

```
.m-standout {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    .standout-heading {
        font-size: 34px;
        width: 31.28834%;
        align-self: center;
    }
    .standout-desc {
        width: 52.76074%;
        align-self: center;
    }
    .standout-image {
    }
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sDGxy

**EDIT**
Just noticed that you want the image to span the entire width of the container to do this a couple more changes are required:

**SCSS:**

**Change:**

```
.standout-image {
}
```

**To:**

```
.standout-image, .standout-image img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

**Change:**

```
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
```

**To:**

```
<div class="standout-image"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt=""></div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kgxdA

Answer (score 2):

I suggest wrapping the heading and desc in a new flex container (I've named it flexbox) and removing flex property from m-standout, here's a modification of your pen -

```
.m-standout {
    .flexbox {
     display: flex;
      .standout-heading {
        flex: 1;
          font-size: 34px;
          width: 31.28834%;
          align-self: center;

      }

       .standout-desc {
         flex: 1;
          width: 52.76074%;
        align-self: center;
      }
    }

    .standout-image {
      width: 100%; /* Remove this if you want the image to take it's natural width */
    }
}
```

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cHmIC